# Is the group of integer points on a finite-type group scheme over Z finitely presented?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups

> Let $G$ be a group scheme of finite type over $\mathbf{Z}$.  Must $G(\mathbf{Z})$ be finitely presented?

(The question is inspired by a not yet successful attempt to answer [a question of Brian Conrad](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22211/finiteness-property-of-automorphism-scheme).)

A few special cases:

1. If $G$ is the Néron model of an abelian variety over $\mathbf{Q}$, then a positive answer amounts to the Mordell-Weil theorem (combine with restriction of scalars to get the full Mordell-Weil theorem).
2. If $G$ is the restriction of scalars of $\mathbf{G}_m$ from the ring of integers of a number field down to $\mathbf{Z}$, then a positive answer follows from Dirichlet's unit theorem.

Answer (score 14):

It follows from Theorem 6.12 of Borel and Harsh-Chandra, "Arithmetic subgroups of algebraic groups", that $G(\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated if $G$ is affine. Perhaps one can combine this with Chevalley's theorem to deduce finite generation in the general (not necessarily affine) case.

EDIT  (Added idea for proof of general case; see also Torsten Ekedahl's comment below)

EDIT (Proof completed (assuming $G$ is separated) and simplfied using comments of BCnrd below)

As discussed in the comments below, we may assume $G$ is flat and we may also assume it is connected. By Chevalley's theorem, there is an affine subgroup scheme $H_{\mathbb{Q}}$ of the generic fibre $G_\mathbb{Q}$ of $G$
such that the quotient $G_{\mathbb{Q}}/H_\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian variety. Let $H$ be the Zariski closure of $H_{\mathbb{Q}}$ in $G$ with the reduced induced structure. Then $H$ is a closed subgroup scheme of $G$. By a theorem of Raynaud (see comment of BCnrd below for the reference) $H$ is also affine.

We have an incusion of groups

$G(\mathbb{Z})/H(\mathbb{Z}) \subset G(\mathbb{Q})/H(\mathbb{Q}) \subset (G_{\mathbb{Q}}/H_{\mathbb{Q}})(\mathbb{Q})$.

Since $G_{\mathbb{Q}}/H_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an abelian variety, by the Mordell-Weil theorem $(G_{\mathbb{Q}}/H_{\mathbb{Q}})(\mathbb{Q})$ is a finitely generated abelian group, hence so is $G(\mathbb{Z})/H(\mathbb{Z})$. Since $H(\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated by the Borel-Harish-Chandra theorem, it follows that $G(\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated.

Comment: I think it's a bit more subtle. For cocompact lattices, I think you still need to use Weil's paper, and, as I recall, one of the reasons Kazhdan defined Property (T) was to prove that nonuniform lattices were finitely generated (a group with Property (T) is compactly generated, so discrete implies finitely generated).

Comment: Well, I am not an expert and am only quoting the theorem; here the question is one about arithmetic groups so one does not have to deal with general (non-arithmetic) lattices. (If one embeds G in $GL_{n,Z}$ as closed subgroupscheme then if I am not mistaken, $G(\mathbb{Z})$ is the same as the $G_Z$ in their theorem.)

Comment: Well, first of all, $G(\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{R})$ might not be reductive, as in the examples given in the question. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see why the argument works even in the semisimple setting. It is a lattice, which is not accidentally analogous to Dirichlet's unit theorem, but I still don't see how you get to finite generation for a generic discrete subgroup of finite covolume in $G(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The reduction to the affine case should be reasonably simple at least if $G$ is smooth: Let $A$ be the maximal abelian quotient of $G_{\mathbb Q}$ and $\mathcal A$ its Néron model. Then we get a map $G \to \mathcal A$. If the kernel of this map is affine we are through, certainly it is affine over $\mathbb Q$. I have one question on the affine case though. Is there no problem if $G$ (over $\mathbb Q$ is not reductive?

Comment: @Torsten Ekedahl. There is no reductivity assumption in the theorem I quoted (Theorem 6.5 deals with the reductive case.) I admit to not having read the proof so perhaps I am still missing something.

Comment: @Matthew Stover. I am not giving an argument, just a reference. In particular, I am not claiming finite generation for generic discrete subgroups of finite covolume in $G(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @unknown: Sorry, should have looked at the result (which I have now done and can confirm your formulation). In the affine case there remains (a minor point surely) the problem of commensurability between $G(\mathbb Z)$ and $G_{\mathbb Z}$ for some embedding of $G_{\mathbb Q}$ in some $\mathrm{GL}_n$. This is OK as the embedding can be done over $\mathbb Z$ (when $G$ is flat but we may assume that) as has been discussed in another thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22078/smooth-linear-algebraic-groups-over-the-dual-numbers.

Comment: @Torsten Ekedahl. The mathscinet review only mentions the reductive case and I was also initially misled by that. I was implicitly assuming flatness (c.f. my first comment); I suppose one can replace G with the Zariski closure of its generic fibre (with the reduced scheme structure) ion order to achive this.

Comment: Let's assume $G$ separated. A $G/H$ is not needed to prove finite generation, since $G(\mathbf{Z})/H(\mathbf{Z})$ is subgroup of $G(\mathbf{Q})/H(\mathbf{Q})$, a subgroup of (finitely generated) Mordell-Weil group of ab var. $G_{\mathbf{Q}}/H_{\mathbf{Q}}$. A more serious point is to prove $H$ is affine! Since finite type with affine generic fiber, it is affine over $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$ for some $N$. To prove affine is problem over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ for each $p|N$. Now use SGA3 result of Raynaud (needs sep'tdness) that appears with proof as Prop. 3.1 of Prasad-Yu paper "Quasi-reductive groups". 

Comment: @BCnrd: Thanks for spotting the typos. I have also incuded the assumption that G is separated. 

Comment: Sorry, now I see. I didn't have the paper handy last night, but did know that 6.5 is the heart of the paper. You do get finite generation from their argument. All I could recall is that 6.5 shows there's an open set $O$ for which $G(\mathbb{R}) = O G(\mathbb{Z}}) K O$, but also $|O O^{-1} \cap g_1 G(\mathbb{Z}) g_2| < \infty$ for $g_j \in G(\mathbb{Q})$. The last condition gives it to you.